# Placing store and update logic in Laravel 8 form request

Tags: php, validation, laravel, authorization

I want some opinions about my code that implements store and update for a Laravel 8 form request.  The `make` function is for storing the data and the `update` function is for updating the data.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AdminRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        if (request()->isMethod('post')) {
            $rule = 'required';
        }


        if (request()->isMethod('put')) {
            $rule = 'sometimes';
        }

        return [
            'name' => ['required'],
            'email' => [$rule, 'email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore(optional($this)->admin)],
            'password' => [$rule, Rules\Password::defaults(), 'confirmed']
        ];
    }

    public function make()
    {
        $data = $this->validated();
        $data['email_verified_at'] = \now();

        return Admin::create($data);
    }

    public function update($admin)
    {
        $data = $this->validated();
        $data['email_verified_at'] = \now();

        return $admin->update($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public function authorize()
> {
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Should all users be able to perform such actions? Typically this method would ensure that the user has a certain role (e.g. admin).

---

> ```
>     if (request()->isMethod('post')) {
>         $rule = 'required';
>     }
>
>
>     if (request()->isMethod('put')) {
>         $rule = 'sometimes';
>     }
> ```

Since the route files weren't included it is difficult to know which HTTP verbs are allowed for the requests, but given these lines we could posit that they are only allowed for `POST` and `PUT` requests. If that is true then the lines above could be simplified to a ternary:

```
$rule = request()->isMethod('post') ? 'required' : 'sometimes';
```

---

Both `make()` and `update()` have the same first two lines. Those two lines could be abstracted to a separate method  - e.g.

```
private static function getValidatedData()
{
    $data = $this->validated();
    $data['email_verified_at'] = \now();
    return $data;
}
```

Though that would mean adding six lines just to eliminate four. If those two lines had been repeated more than twice then it would be worth it.